# ThingsBoard: add multiple system administrator

Tags: thingsboard

As my understanding, Thingsboard has 3 kind of users - 
**System Administrator**, **Tenant Administrators**, **Customer Users**.

System Administrator can make multiple tenant administrators.  But I didn't find how to add additional **System Administrator**

How can I make my Thingsboard to have multiple system admins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved to postgres. In database table tb_user there is one entry with authority field set as "SYS_ADMIN". It is simple text. 
So I did this:

```
update tb_user set authority='SYS_ADMIN' where email='myemail@aaaa';
```

I got two admins now. But remember - it is a hack not a solution. This altered user is still related to existing tenatns so it might cause some trouble in the future. Probably a more work with database cleanup is needed.